# TensorFlow RNN example from book (word2vec, embeddings, )

Tags: python, tensorflow, nonetype, sess.run

Guided by the book with name "Learning TensorFlow. A Guide to Building Deep Learning Systems (Tom Hope, Yehezkel S. Reshe , and Itay Lieder)" I'm trying to implement simple RNN network with word2vec approach.

On page 101 (Chapter 6, Text II: Word Vectors, Advanced RNN, and Embedding Visualization) authors give an example with RNN implementation (code below), but in sess.run method I got `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Env:

- Docker (Client: 17.06.0-ce, Server: 17.06.0-ce)
- Jupyter 4.3.0
- Conda 4.3.30
- Python 3.6.1
- Tensorflow 1.4.0
- Numpy 1.12.1

--

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

batch_size = 64
embedding_dimension = 5
negative_samples = 8
LOG_DIR = "/opt/notebooks/tlog/word2vec_intro"
digit_to_word_map = { 1:"One",2:"Two", 3:"Three", 4:"Four", 5:"Five",
                      6:"Six",7:"Seven",8:"Eight",9:"Nine" }
sentences = []
# Create two kinds of sentences - sequences of odd and even digits
for i in range(10000):
    rand_odd_ints = np.random.choice(range(1,10,2),3)
    sentences.append(" ".join([digit_to_word_map[r] for r in rand_odd_ints]))
    rand_even_ints = np.random.choice(range(2,10,2),3)
    sentences.append(" ".join([digit_to_word_map[r] for r in rand_even_ints]))


# Map words to indices
word2index_map = {}
index = 0
for sent in sentences:
    for word in sent.lower().split():
        if word not in word2index_map:
            word2index_map[word] = index
            index += 1

index2word_map = { index: word for word, index in word2index_map.items() }
vocabulary_size = len(index2word_map)

# Generate skip-gram pairs
skip_gram_pairs = []
for sent in sentences:
    tokenized_sent = sent.lower().split()
    for i in range(1, len(tokenized_sent)-1):
        word_context_pair = [[word2index_map[tokenized_sent[i-1]],
                              word2index_map[tokenized_sent[i+1]]],
                              word2index_map[tokenized_sent[i]]]
        skip_gram_pairs.append([word_context_pair[1],
                                word_context_pair[0][0]])
        skip_gram_pairs.append([word_context_pair[1],
                                word_context_pair[0][1]])

def get_skipgram_batch(batch_size):
    instance_indices = list(range(len(skip_gram_pairs)))
    np.random.shuffle(instance_indices)
    batch = instance_indices[:batch_size]
    x = [skip_gram_pairs[i][0] for i in batch]
    y = [[skip_gram_pairs[i][1]] for i in batch]
    return x, y

# Batch example
# x_batch, y_batch = get_skipgram_batch(8)
# x_batch
# y_batch
# [index2word_map[word] for word in x_batch]
# [index2word_map[word[0]] for word in y_batch]

# Input data, labels
train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])


with tf.name_scope("embeddings"):
    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_dimension], -1.0, 1.0), name='embedding'
    )
    # This is essentially a lookup table
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

# Create variables for the NCE loss
nce_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_dimension],
    stddev = 1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_dimension))
)

nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.nce_loss(weights = nce_weights, biases = nce_biases, inputs = embed,
       labels = train_labels, num_sampled = negative_samples, num_classes =
                vocabulary_size
    )
)


# Learning rate decay
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable = False)
learningRate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate = 0.1,
                                          global_step = global_step,
                                          decay_steps = 1000,
                                          decay_rate = 0.95,
                                          staircase = True)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(loss)

# Merge all summary ops
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR, graph = tf.get_default_graph())

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with open(os.path.join(LOG_DIR,'metadata.tsv'), "w") as metadata:
        metadata.write('Name\tClass\n')
        for k, v in index2word_map.items():
            metadata.write('%s\t%d\n' % (v, k))

    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    embedding = config.embeddings.add()
    embedding.tensor_name = embeddings.name
    # Link embedding to its metadata file
    embedding.metadata_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR,'metadata.tsv')
    projector.visualize_embeddings(train_writer, config)

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for step in range(1000):
        x_batch, y_batch = get_skipgram_batch(batch_size)

        summary, _ = sess.run(
            train_step, 
            feed_dict = {
                train_inputs: x_batch,
                train_labels: y_batch
            }
        )
        # train_writer.add_summary(summary, step)

        if step % 100 == 0:
            saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, "w2v_model.ckpt"), step)
            loss_value = sess.run(loss,
                                  feed_dict = {train_inputs:x_batch,
                                               train_labels:y_batch})

        print("Loss at %d: %.5f" % (step, loss_value))

    # Normalize embeddings before using
    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
    normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
    normalized_embeddings_matrix = sess.run(normalized_embeddings)

    ref_word = normalized_embeddings_matrix[word2index_map["one"]]
    cosine_dists = np.dot(normalized_embeddings_matrix,ref_word)
    ff = np.argsort(cosine_dists)[::-1][1:10]
    for f in ff:
        print(index2word_map[f])
        print(cosine_dists[f])
```

And result

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e91d4f09d595> in <module>()
    143             feed_dict = {
    144                 train_inputs: x_batch,
--> 145                 train_labels: y_batch
    146             }
    147         )

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But before sess.run `print(y_batch)` give us (As in book)

```
[[4], [6], [0], [4], [7], [3], [2], [3], [3], [8], [4], [2], [2], [1], [6], [1], [0], [3], [5], [6], [5], [8], [0], [7], [7], [0], [0], [8], [2], [2], [4], [6], [3], [7], [1], [1], [4], [8], [6], [5], [4], [7], [8], [6], [1], [3], [4], [2], [2], [4], [5], [6], [3], [0], [5], [2], [2], [2], [0], [4], [5], [3], [0], [4]]
```

What I should to do to run this example correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add merged value in your run function:

```
summary, _ = sess.run(
            [merged, train_step], 
            feed_dict = {
                train_inputs: x_batch,
                train_labels: y_batch
            }
        )
```

Or delete it if you do not want this information:

```
loss = sess.run(
            train_step, 
            feed_dict = {
                train_inputs: x_batch,
                train_labels: y_batch
            }
        )
```